# Python list index out of range error?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a python script that gets the last line of a text file and splits it. Some users have been emailing me that the list index out of range error keeps popping up. here is relevant code:

```
if Data.closed == True:
    Data = open("Data.txt", "r")
#
lines = len(Data.readlines())
Data.close()

Data = open("Data.txt", "r")
if lines > 1:
    for x in range(0, lines):
        lastLine = Data.readline()
    #   

else:
    fatalError("ERROR:Map file has no data!!", True)            
#               
lastLineBroken = lastLine.split("|")
lstLnBrokLen = len(lastLineBroken)
lat = lastLineBroken[0]
lon = lastLineBroken[1]
Data.close()
```

Comment: What is `lines`? This clearly isn't all your code.

Comment: On what line does the error appear? If there is no `'|'` in the `lastline`, `lon = lastLineBroken[1]` will give the error.

Comment: Sorry! i forgot about that part. added

Comment: You should [use the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4) to work with files in Python, and that's a really bad way to iterate over a file - files are iterators, loop over it directly! With your current method, you have to read the whole file twice just to loop over it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last line and split it via lat/lon, then try:

```
from collections import deque

with open('yourfile') as fin:
    last = deque(fin, 1)
    try:
        lat, lon = last[0].split('|', 3)[:2]
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        pass # uh oh... no line, or no data in it...
```

If you had a really large file and didn't fancy iterating through it, then another approach (although most likely overkill by the looks of it):

```
import mmap

with open('yourfile') as fin:
    try:
        mm = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
        last_line = mm[mm.rfind('\n') + 1:]
        lat, lon = last_line.split('|', 3)[:2]
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        pass # uh oh....
```

Comment: +1 - the `deque` is the neatest way to get the last line of the file. It'll iterate nice and quickly.

Comment: The  lat and lon is separated by a |

Comment: I tried this  http://pastebin.com/TvXddGhn but it threw the error. here is the data file http://pastebin.com/qJ5k5nrG

Comment: @user3157628 Firsly, it's weird to check if it's closed and then reopen it - and could lead to issues (is it open in the right mode?) - just open it directly in the `with` statement whatever, and it will work correctly. It's also worth noting it's a sign of an issue if you think it's possible a file might be either open or closed - using the `with` statement through your code should ensure you know exactly where it's open or closed (and ensure it gets closed properly).

Comment: @lattyware I tried it the otherway and it still gave me the error.

Comment: The error is because you have more than two values on each line - you should really use the `csv` module here.

Comment: @lattyware Could you give me an example on how to use csv for this purpose?

Comment: @user3157628 There are plenty of examples on StackOverflow - do a search for read csv python and I'm sure you'll find a plethora of examples. Or just read [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) - they are good.

Comment: @user3157628 I made the false assumption that there's only 2 columns per row, I've limited the split now....

Comment: @JonClements That seems to work now!!! Im now gonna try and figure out what it does :p thanks

Comment: What does deque actually do?

Comment: @user3157628 http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add a check that you break the line into enough parts:

```
if len(lastLineBroken) >= 2:
    lat, lon = lastLineBroken[:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the last element of the list (last line)

```
   lines = Data.readlines()
   if lines:
       lastLine = lines[-1]
```

Comment: While better than the OP's method, this is still a bad way of doing this - it requires reading the whole file into memory. The obvious solution is `for lastLine in data: pass`, which will populate `lastLine`, however, that will be slower than Jon Clement's solution - the `deque`, which is the best way to do this.

Comment: Thats true. Deque is the best way.